# Three.js - Animate object size

Tags: canvas, jquery-animate, three.js

I've been following this tutorial: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/webgl/html5-canvas-webgl-cylinder-with-three-js/ (or just copy&pasting it). It works very well (FF only I think), but for my "project" I need to animate the size of the Cylinder. How can this be done?

The rotation is animated like this:

```
three.cylinder.rotation.x += angleChange;
```

I've tried several things like `size.height`, `.height`, `scale.height`, `scale[0]` and so on, but I can't find the correct function.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the `animate()` function, try this:

```
three.cylinder.scale.set( 1, Math.abs( Math.sin( time * 0.0002 ) ), 1 );
```

This will scale the internal y-dimension, and leave the x- and z-dimensions unchanged. Due to the orientation of the cylinder, the y-dimension is, in this case, the length.

Comment: Also, for simplicity: `three.cylinder.scale.y = Math.abs( Math.sin( time * 0.0002 ) );`

Comment: Also even by defining 'time' as a number, the animation is instant.