# Animate object's size in THREEjs

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, scale

Using THREE.js I would like to animate the size of an object so it slowly shrinks into nothingness.

Using answers from [Three.js - Animate object size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482082/three-js-animate-object-size)  I can change the size of an object, but this size change is instant and I want the change to happen over a period of time (3 seconds). Plus the question is old :)

This is my current code. backwardMeshOct is simply a THREE.Mesh(geometry, material):

```
      var time = 20;
      function animate() {
        backwardMeshOct.scale.x = Math.abs( Math.sin( time * 50 ) );
      }

      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

I've tried altering `var time` and what `time` is multiplied by but the result is still the same, an instant size scale on x.

Thanks for your help doods and doobs.

Comment: What about adding a `setTimeout(function() { backwardMeshOct.scale.x = ... }, 3000)` so that your scale changes after 3 seconds or a `setTimeout(function() { time = /* a new value */ }, 3000)` so that the time variable changes after 3 seconds ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find it easier to use a library like Tween.JS.  You'll be able to define a starting value, a target value, and a time delta for the change!

Check out the answer to this question for how it can work with Three: [Tween JS basics on three JS cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739954/tween-js-basics-on-three-js-cube)

If you aren't able to use Tween, try a THREE.Clock object to keep track of the time and scale your mesh appropriately.  I made one in a global scope (before init) and then used it to count to 3 seconds:

```
function render() {
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    var t = clock.getElapsedTime();

    if (t >= 3.0)
    {
        clock = new THREE.Clock;
        mesh.scale.set(1,1,1);
    }
    else
    {
        mesh.scale.x = 1-(t/3.0);
        mesh.scale.y = 1-(t/3.0);
        mesh.scale.z = 1-(t/3.0);   
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/adamfinley/ac6zxgt6/1/

Comment: I want the answer to be only using Three.js. I am not able to add Tween.JS in my current project due to restrictions from my employer :(

Comment: @IanSteffy sure! I edited my post with some code to do it in Three only.

Comment: The solution without Tween works however, I have not tested the Tween solution. I hope someone else will.